# SwiftUI MenuBarExtra with custom view in menubar instead of just icon and label

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, menubar, custom-view

I read that one can use [`MenuBarExtra`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menubarextra) in a Swift macOS application to create a menubar application. An icon with a label can be displayed in the menubar. However, clicking on the entry opens a context menu that can contain rich content.
I'd like to use this easy, convenient and small code but instead of displaying only an icon and a label I need to display a custom view. That view will contain multiple labels in different colors and will get updated continuously. Is this possible with `MenuBarExtra`? I have no code yet. For example [iStat](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) has such a menu.

Comment: Long story short: It's not possible. You have to go for `NSStatusItem`.

Comment: @vadian I feared that. Can you elaborate a bit how it works, which steps are involved, pitfalls and how much more work this is?

Comment: Please read [this](https://multi.app/blog/pushing-the-limits-nsstatusitem)

Comment: @vadian many thanks, good source, will read through it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my testing on macOS 13.5.2, you cannot do this with `MenuBarExtra`. You'll need to use the [`NSStatusItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem) API from AppKit.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DesktopTestApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        
        // Add this line ---->
        MenuBarExtra("App", systemImage: "square.stack.3d.down.forward") {
            VStack {
                Text("hello world")
                // your views goes here
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .background(.windowBackground)
        }.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
        // ------------------------ 
    }  
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to display an (unsupported) custom view rather than a (supported) system image